# Architectures for neural networks and a 2D tensor in R

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

Hello I am trying to build a neural network in R, and so far it works fine as shown in the following code:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(tidyverse)

nn_dat = iris %>% as_tibble %>%
  mutate(sepal_l_feat = scale(Sepal.Length),
         sepal_w_feat = scale(Sepal.Width),
         petal_l_feat = scale(Petal.Length),
         petal_w_feat = scale(Petal.Width),          
         class_num    = as.numeric(Species) - 1, # factor, so = 0, 1, 2
         class_label  = Species) %>%
  select(contains("feat"), class_num, class_label)

nn_dat %>% head(3)

set.seed(2022)

test_f = 0.40
nn_dat = nn_dat %>%
  mutate(partition = sample(c('train','test'), nrow(.), replace = TRUE, prob = c(1 - test_f, test_f)))

x_train = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'train') %>% select(contains("feat")) %>% as.matrix
y_train = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'train') %>% pull(class_num) %>% to_categorical(3)
x_test  = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'test')  %>% select(contains("feat")) %>% as.matrix
y_test  = nn_dat %>% filter(partition == 'test')  %>% pull(class_num) %>% to_categorical(3)

model = keras_model_sequential()
model %>% 
  ## Number of columns
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax')
model %>% summary

model %>% compile(
  loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics   = c('accuracy')
)

history = model %>% fit(
  x = x_train, y = y_train,
  epochs           = 200,
  batch_size       = 20,
  validation_split = 0
)
plot(history)

perf = model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(perf)
```

however, I would like to see if there is a better architecture for my model, I am using iris just because it is public but I am working with other data.

so in particular here:

```
model %>% 
  ## Number of predictors
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax')
model %>% summary
```

I am using 4 units because I have 4 columns and 3 at the end, for the result, however if I wanted to add more layers in between, how should I go about deciding on the architecture?

Any recommendation is welcome

Comment: Deciding architecture or hyperparameter values, especially if the use case is ambiguous, is not simple. Some advice can be found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20222/how-to-decide-neural-network-architecture). Since the Iris data set is very popular many blogs describe different setups, and are good sources for ideas. For actual data, ideas can be sourced from literature. It is a bit [messy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms), but querying other SE sites might help.

Comment: Thanks @DonaldSeinen, I have been looking for papers, but maybe I am not looking for the right keywords?